# Verify django loaddata progress

Tags: django, migration

I'm trying to migrate from sqlite to a google managed postgres db. It worked locally with a postgres db that runs within docker, but when I try

```
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

for the remote db the cursor just blinks forever but I don't know if something is happening. How can I verify that the process is doing something? I'm using `cloud_sql_proxy` to connect to the db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add some verbosity, the option is `-v`/`--verbose`; from `python manage.py help loaddata`:

```
-v {0,1,2,3}, --verbosity {0,1,2,3}
                  Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                  2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
```

For example, you can go for maximum verbosity:

```
python manage.py -v 3 loaddata db.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked at the end, but I had to wait several minutes. So, just be patient.